# How to know the location of lualatex.exe?

Tags: windows, latex, filepath

The TexLive system uses lualatex.  I have an application that needs to know the location of `lualatex.exe`.

Now, if `lualatex` is in the PATH evnvironmental variable, I'm in luck.  If it isn't there, then I have to go and do a full-computer file-search for the file.

Is there another way I could find it?

I mean, is there some lualatex registry value or directory that is standard in *every* installation?

*[update]*

Okay, I have found a certain standard; if TexLive is installed, in the %userprofile% directory, there will be directories for `.texlive2012` or `.texlive2013` - I wonder if there is a way to use that knowledge to find the installation directory.  The contents of those folders do not reveal anything, however.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what LaTeX installation you are using. If it's MikTeX (under 64 bit Windows) it will be in

> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\

So I think it will always be in "the bin folder".

Comment: You don't understand; in Windows a user can choose a different install path, so you can't know for sure where the `bin` folder is!

Comment: That's what I meant by _it will always be in "the bin folder"_. You will never know where the user has installed his TeX. You may only know where it would be installed by default and if it's not you'll have to ask the user.

Comment: Yes, but if no environmental variable is set, I have no way to know where the bin folder actually is!  It could be `c:\texlive\2013\win32\bin` or c:\texlive\2012\win32\bin` or `c:\texlive\win32\bin`.  I was hoping for some other trick based on some file in the user's appdata directory or some registry key.